# half bridge converter weird primary current waveform

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I build up a half bridge converter(as illustated in figure), today I measured current of one of the primary switchs(MOSFET), but something seems weird, while I expecting a triangle current shape, the current is measured as illustrated in graph with blue one, by the way yellow shape is belongs to MOSFET gate signal, current suddenşy rises at the end of gate signal, I don't know whether Transformer saturated or not? parameters when I captured the graph is; input voltage 240V (120V for per capacitor) 0.43Ampers, output voltage 130V with 200 ohm resistive load, efficiency is about %80-85, duty is %50, transformer turns ratio: 1:1.4   Any comment will be appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that T1 and T2 aren't switching on together?

Comment: Your scope has the ability to save screenshots, you might want to use that

Comment: @transistor, İf you mean at the same time, yes I am sure, otherwise my dc supply at the input would be short circuit and probably I can't get any output energy at output side.

Comment: Do you have any guaranteed dead-time between the gate drive signals which would help to ensure that T1 & T2 aren't on together? A scope pic with both gate drive signals would help. But if its not cross-conduction then saturation is your most likely culprit. What happens if you shorten the gate pulse a little?

Comment: @brhans, yes I am sure there is no cross conduction, what I don't understand is why current doesn't start to rise at the beginging of the gate signal, as if someting delay or prevent the operation of MOSFET.

Comment: Maybe it does - what is the scale of your 'scope? Try zooming in a bit. You could be so far zoomed out just to fit that (possibly) core saturation current spike that you don't notice the 'normal' current ramp before it.

Comment: @brhans , maybe you're right I will try it tomarrow and, I will increase the switcing freq. if transformer saturates, ı may get rid of this current spike

Comment: What does your gate driver look like? Is it a combined high and low side driver IC (such as the IR2110), or do you use a gate drive transformer, or some discrete component solution? How do you probe the MOSFET current? Which transistor are you measuring the gate drive voltage and drain current from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your instinct is correct: that is a fairly typical drain current waveform when your core is saturating.

Your MOSFETs are not delayed, they are turning on when the gate voltage shows they should.  You can see the current ramping up slowly when the FET is on, while it says flat when its off.  Unfortunately, based on the waveform, your transformer is very poorly suited for your requirements.

You have **way** too much winding inductance (too many turns) for your core...too many turns on too high of a permeability core. There is so much inductance that the current is rising glacially slow, and even that trickle of current is enough to make the nonlinear nature of the core be almost immediately apparent, distorting even the pre-saturation part of the wave slightly due to the more minor roll off of inductance before the ferrite just loses it.  Then, being ferrite, it begins to saturate like a brick wall as the small amount of current quickly overwhelms the core.

Transformers at higher frequencies can be somewhat forgiving when it comes to saturation as long as it is not too severe.  They can remain functional, more or less, but you're introducing significant high frequency harmonics onto the secondary due to the distorted waveform, which can cause all sorts of problems and cost efficiency.  A simple resistive load is going to tolerate the harmonics the best, but other types of loads, or larger ones, will probably make your efficiency plummet.

Anyway, transformer saturation is sort of wily in that things can appear to be working (and are, at least if you don't care about EMI, harmonic losses, efficiency, overheating) for many cases of core saturation.  If you saturate an inductor in a DC/DC converter, usually something is kind enough to explode or at least catch fire, alerting you to the problem quickly and obviously.  Transformers are not so nice and like to hide their problems and act like everything is fine, even if its not.

I would try reducing the number of turns while preserving the ratio.  I know you need a lot of inductance to handle that much voltage no load, but you have too much even then.  At 30KHz, the MOSFETs aren't even able to ramp the current up much at all.  You should be ok to reduce the turns a bit.  Just remember, inductance is proportional to the square of the turns, so don't over do it.  On the plus, if you over do it, it will probably melt or catch fire, and then you'll know (unlike saturation, sneaky bugger).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, today I doubled switching frequency, its better and waveform resemble what it should be, but problem didn't solved completely,@metacollin  if I am wrong please correct me , more primary turn number isn't better to solve saturation issue , because it reduces Bmax, right now reducing primary turns will be very hard for me, I may have to do everything from begining for transformer, what do you think abaout leaving a little air gap? I will try right now?